# Is it correct to create uncommitted instances in a Django model manager?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models `Element` and `Group` with `Element` having a FK to `Group`

My instanciation of `Element` instances is quite complex and so I've created a custom manager.

```py
class ElementManager(models.Manager.from_queryset(ElementQuerySet)):
    def create_element(self, group, **kwargs):
        # Some logic
        ...

        # Create the instance with computed params
        return super.create(**params)
```

I now want a way to "build" an uncommitted instance to `bulk_create` multiple `Element` instances and I wonder where this logic should be located.

I could put it in the `Manager`:

```py
class ElementManager(models.Manager.from_queryset(ElementQuerySet)):
    def build_element(self, group, **kwargs):
        # Some logic
        ...

        # Create the instance with computed params
        return super.model(**params)

    def create_element(self, group, **kwargs):
        self.build_element(group, **kwargs).save()
```

However I feel that is not correct for a `Manager` to create uncommitted instances since the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Manager) specifies that: "*A `Manager` is the interface through which database query operations are provided to Django models*" and `.build_element()` does not provid *"database query operations"*.

Could someone explain to me where this piece of code should be located to respect the Django logic ?

Comment: A `@staticmethod` on the model.